# After Debian installation, how to add Grub Entries for new/other bootable disks/installations?

Tags: debian, system-installation, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have two SSDs, one is for my Windows 7, and one is for testing and tweaking it (like installing Linux, or other operating systems...).

I've already installed Windows 7 on the first SSD,
and I tried to install Debian distribution on the second SSD, the installation was successful.

But the problem is that I installed something called boot loader into first SSD (which Windows 7 is installed), so if I run second SSD, nothing happens and if I run the first SSD, automatically Debian boot loader runs, and what thing fundamentally makes me annoying is that there is no option for Windows, just for Debian. (I thought I can use both of the choices if I install the boot loader into any SSD.)

If I open the SSD which Win installed, I can see those files and folders.

```
[Folder] Boot
[Folder] Documents and Settings
[Folder] Intel
[Folder] Perflogs
[Folder] ProgramData
[Folder] Program files
[Folder] Program files (x86)
[Folder] Recovery
[Folder] $Recycle.Bin
[Folder] System Volume Information
[Folder] Users
[Folder] Windows
[File] bootmgr
[File] BOOTSECT.BAK
[File] hiberfil.sys
[File] pagefile.sys
```

I think those all folders & files have relationships to Windows OS, but actually I don't know. (I just googled it.)

Can I change the directory of the boot loader or delete it?
What can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on which boot-loader was installed. If its a standard Debian install it should be GRUB2.

Boot the computer with all disks containing bootable installations attached and powered.

you need to open Root Terminal application to open a terminal as root, then enter these commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install os-prober
```

if os-prober package is already installed, apt will let you know, without doing any changes to the system.

Then edit **/etc/default/grub** and make sure you have a line like

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

you can edit the file using a GUI text editor like Gedit, or a CLI Editor, such as Vim or Nano.

Using Gedit:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

You need to close gedit to be able to use the terminal again

Using Nano

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

I don't recommend using vim if you're a beginner, it takes some time to get used to it's operation modes and interface.

Once you're done with editing the file, **if necessary**, enter this command

```
update-grub
```

**Note:** You can skip the file editing process on your first try, but if that doesn't work you'll need to do it, then retry update-grub command.

Comment: More complete answer than mine; well done :)

Comment: @AlexStragies thanks :D, although I missed the **very important** part: _start the computer with both disks attached_ lol

Comment: Yeah, I think his problem initially was, that the windows SSD was disconnected during the Debian install (, which normally picks up other, foreign installations, and auto-adds GRUB entries for them)

Comment: @EunsuJang I'm glad it worked well for you.

Comment: @AlexStragies It seems that was exactly the problem

Comment: Can I ask you one more question please? If I re-install or install another distribution on the second SSD, do I need to passively remove the boot loader from my SSD which Win7 installed? or I don't need to think about that(Is it automatically been removed if I remove the distro?)?

Comment: @EunsuJang If you reinstall Debian. Windows or install another distribution , _**in most cases**_, the bootloader  will be replaced by the new operating system specific bootloader. This presents no problems if the new OS is a Linux distro, most GNU/Linux systems come with a multi-boot capable bootloader such as Grub or Lilo, however, Windows bootloader doesn't support this feature, and you'll need to reinstall Grub _or Lilo_, there's an utility that eases this process called "Rescatux".

Comment: @EunsuJang Removing an OS removes also most part of the bootloader, but not the bootloader header that is stored in the MBR (Master Boot Record) of the first drive, or other if you (were allowed to) specify it. The header code of the bootleader is the entry point to the bootloader, a 512 bytes chunk that includes the needed instructions to jump where the actual bootloader resides so it can be loader to memory and start the boot process, The BIOS looks for this specific...

Comment: ...chuck of code to boot the system, if it can't find it in the MBR of the first drive it looks for other drives until a match is found, if it cant find any it will print an error on the screen, something: _System drive is missing_. If it find it, it passes control to the bootloader header code, ...

Comment: witch looks for the bootloader and if it can't find it, let's say, because you remove your entire system, it will print a message to the screen. So, although it won't get removed if you remove the OS, it will carry almost the same consequences, However, there's some situations that you would want to get rid of this orphaned headers, eg: you add a new disk and that disk became the first drive, then you can use something like Rescatux to wipe the MBR of a specific drive. Hope this clarifies the scenario a little bit

Comment: I installed Fedora workstation on my desktop, (I am still keeping the Windows OS) When I boot with Windows, there I can see black CLI with comments like No file, Grub rescue... I guess that the problem occurred because I deleted Debian, can I remove or do more things for successful booting of Windows?

Comment: which version of fedora workstation are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version of it, and I have downloaded it from the official website of Fedora Project, on yesterday. I apologize that I didn't write detail information.

Comment: Use rescatux CD tool: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/ . Boot from there, then you have two courses of action. 1.- Click on Restore Grub, which will attempt to install grub to the MBR, then Update Grub, which will create the list of your OSes. or 2.- Restore Windows MBR, if you just want to get back to Windows for now.

Answer (score 5):

You could:

- start the computer with both disks attached,
- boot into (your currently only choice) Debian
- run `update-grub`

It should detect Windows on the first Disk, and add an entry to the boot-loader choices.

And you could then optionally install grub also to the other disk boot sector by running `grub-install /dev/sdb`

`sdb` is what I assume to be the device node for the second attached disk, else try `sda`